# WMS layer not working in OpenLayers (Geoportal)

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapping

I tried to implement layers in WMS format in openlayers 6. This layer comes from the Geoportal of the Emilia Romagna region, but I cannot see it on the map. This is the code:

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>`    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    
    <script src="Prova2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep"></script>
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 800px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/build/ol.js"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers example</title>
  </head>
```

The editor does not let me insert the code with the div containing the map on this page `<div id="map" class="map"`, but there is in the code.

JAVASCRIPT:

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {

  var layer2 = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      url: 'http://servizigis.regione.emilia-romagna.it/wms/uso_del_suolo',
      params: {
        'LAYERS': '2017_uso_suolo_ed2020'
      },
      projection: "EPSG:4326",
      /* serverType: 'geoserver',*/
    }),
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }), layer2
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: "EPSG:4326",
      center: [12.42125, 41.838481],
      zoom: 7
    })
  })
}
```

I am a beginner.

Comment: The layer is restricted by scale `<MaxScaleDenominator>188988.095238</MaxScaleDenominator>` which may be an issue here.

Comment: @nmtoken That's correct, zoom should be at least 12 to make layer visible. You should put this into answer.

Comment: Even entering the zoom failed to resolve. On one computer, with an older version of Openlayers it works for me, while on the other it doesn't. I solved it by entering in source ratio: '1'. Thank you